# How can I make the camera follow only the X-axis of my player in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

So I have this code where the camera follows my player, but it follows both the x and y axis. I am making a game like super mario in as3, so I want the camera to follow just the x-axis. Any suggestions?
Here's my code:

```
import flash.events.Event;

import flash.geom.Rectangle;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cameraFollowCharacter);

function cameraFollowCharacter(evt:Event){
root.scrollRect = new Rectangle(player.x - stage.stageWidth/5, player.y - stage.stageHeight/1.27, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight); 
}
```

Comment: You can use a "camera container" instead

Answer (score 0):

'root.scrollRect' should not depend on player.y.
Use a fixed value for the y property.

```
function cameraFollowCharacter(evt:Event){ 
    root.scrollRect = new Rectangle(player.x - stage.stageWidth/5, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight); 
}
```